# How do I ask a friend for friendship essence?

Tags: angry-birds-epic

One of the hints in Angry Birds Epic says "Ask your friends once a day for a Friendship Essence".

I see how to ask friends for opening the friend gates.

But how exactly do I ask for the essence? I went to friendship totem pole, see my friend list. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out... Asking meant clicking on "Ask" link on the **bottom** of my screen where totem pole was.

Once I did, my friend's totem pole showed a red circle with "1" on it. When clicked on that totem pole, it showed my request and a checkmark to acknowledge it.